# Combine the use of authentication both for MVC pages and for Web API pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

I have an MVC 5 web application and can login with a Login.cshtml page and get a cookie and the login works fine. But, I would like to do a login with the Web API and then (maybe) set a cookie so that I am logged in for my MVC pages... (or login with the MVC login and then access the Web API) however the web api returns a bearer token and not a cookie token... so this doesn't work. Is there a way to combine the use of authentication both for my MVC pages and for my Web API pages?

UPDATE:

This isn't really a code issue, more of a conceptual issue.

Normal MVC web pages examine a cookie named, by default, ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie" to determine the requesters identity. This cookie is generated by calling ApplicationSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync.

WebAPI calls, on the other hand, examine the requests headers for an item named Authorization... and uses that value to determine the requesters identity. This is returned from a WebAPI call to "/Token".

These are very different values. My website needs to use both MVC pages *and* WebAPI calls (to dynamically update those pages)... and both need to be authenticated to perform their tasks.

The only method I can think of is to actually authenticate twice... once with a WebAPI call and again with the Login post. (see my Answer below).

This seems very hacky... but I don't understand the authorization code enough to know if there is a more proper way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Please show you code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to achieve this, is to have an authorization server (a Web API generating a token) and token consumption middle-ware in your MVC project. [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) should help. However I have done it like this:

I built an authorization server using JWT with Web API and ASP.Net Identity as explained [here](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/).

Once you do that, your Web APIs `startup.cs` will look like this:

```
 // Configures cookie auth for web apps and JWT for SPA,Mobile apps
 private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
 {
    // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

    // Cookie for old school MVC application
    var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        CookieHttpOnly = true, // JavaScript should use the Bearer
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,                
        LoginPath = new PathString("/api/Account/Login"),
        CookieName = "AuthCookie"
    };
    // Plugin the OAuth bearer JSON Web Token tokens generation and Consumption will be here
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);

    OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
        Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),                
        AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JWTPath"])
    };

    // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
}
```

You can find the `CustomOAuthProvider` and `CustomJwtFormat` classes [here](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AspNetIdentity.WebApi/tree/master/AspNetIdentity.WebApi/Providers).

I wrote a consumption logic (i.e. middleware) in all my other APIs (Resource servers) that I wanted to secure using the same token. Since you want to consume the token generated by the Web API in your MVC project, after implementing the authorization server, you need to the following:

In your MVC app, add this in `startup.cs`:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
        ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);
}

private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthIssuer"];
    string audienceid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceId"];
    byte[] audiencesecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceSecret"]);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { CookieName = "AuthCookie" , AuthenticationType=DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie });

    //// Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            AuthenticationType = "JWT",
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceid },
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audiencesecret)                           
            }

        });
}
```

In your MVC controller, when you receive the token, de-serialize it and generate a cookie from the access token:

```
AccessClaims claimsToken = new AccessClaims();
claimsToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessClaims>(response.Content);
claimsToken.Cookie = response.Cookies[0].Value;               
Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + claimsToken.access_token);
var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticateResult = await ctx.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("JWT");
ctx.Authentication.SignOut("JWT");
var applicationCookieIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticateResult.Identity.Claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
ctx.Authentication.SignIn(applicationCookieIdentity);
```

Generate a machine key and add it in `web.config` of your Web API and ASP.Net MVC site.

With this, a cookie will be created and the `[Authorize]` attribute in the MVC site and the Web API will honor this cookie.

**P.S.** I have done this with a Web API issuing JWT (Authorization server or Auth & resource server) and was able to consume it in an ASP.Net MVC website, SPA Site built in Angular, secure APIs built in python (resource server), spring (resource server) and an Android App.

Comment: I think there's a typo: `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());` should be  `app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);` inside the private method ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this using an external authentication provider for authenticating against Microsoft Azure AD (for example, calling app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication)?

Answer (score 2):

Ugg... what I had to do was use the Login.cshtml form and override the submit... make an Ajax call to get the WebApi bearer token... and then do the form submit to get the actual MVC cookie. So, I'm actually making two login requests... one for the WebApi token and the other for the MVC cookie.

Seem pretty hacky to me... it would be nice if there was some way to sign in to MVC using the bearer token... or a call to the WebApi that would return me a cookie that I can use for normal MVC page requests.

If anyone has a better way I would love to hear it.

This is script code that I added to Login.cshtml:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form:first').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
            var formData = $form.serializeObject(); // https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object
            formData.grant_type = "password";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Token")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: formData, // seems like the data must be in json format
                success: function (data) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('token', data.access_token);
                    $form.get(0).submit(); // do the actual page post now
                },
                error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you're trying to do is have pages served by MVC have javascript that makes calls to Web API methods.  If you're using ASP.NET Identity to handle authentication (which it looks like you're doing), then MVC should be using OAuth tokens that can be passed to Web API for authentication.

Here's a snippet from some javascript code that works for me in a similar situation:

```
var token = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');
var headers = {};
if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
}
$.ajax({
    type: <GET/POSt/...>,
    url: <your api>,
    headers: headers
}).done(function (result, textStatus) {
```

Comment: You're description is exactly right... but the question is how and where do you get the access_token, to store in sessionStorage, in the first place... and where and how do you get the cookie for MVC page authentication.

Comment: The access token gets stored in sessionStorage by the MVC framework, my code doesn't have to store it there. If that's not happening for your code, post how you are configuring ASP.NET Identity/OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar case with you, but i use a different way to authenticate.

I have a web and an api, which all for intranet users. I do not use user's identity to pass web and api. Instead, i created a individual web account, and every time web will use this special account to connect to api.

Because, we also need to make sure that users should not connect to api directly. They should only connect to web ui.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments above, from what I understand, you have a scenario wherein you perform login through browser but also have to invoke web-api methods using ajax calls.

The browser calls are session-cookie based. While the ajax calls from the browser would have the session cookie in the header, what is required is the authentication header to be present for the web-api to perform validation.

So on a successful login you'd also have to generate a web-api based token, set it as a cookie (that is accessible by javascript) and then while making ajax calls, pick it up from the cookie and include it as header in your 'Authorization' header.