# How to authenticate both ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebAPI from one 3rd party Identity provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am struggling to understand how to implement the following scenario:

#### Given:

- Custom 3rd party Identity Server that supports oAuth2 implicit flow (I don't have access to internals, only can receive token)
- ASP.NET MVC app (Service Provider)
- ASP.NET WebAPI (provides 'Orders' endpoint that's being accessed from MVC app)

#### Problem:

Need to log-in to MVC app through Identity Server and then use the received JWT token to authenticate to WebAPI when requesting 'Orders' endpoint.

Is it a possible scenario and if yes then how do I do it?

Comment: Yes it is possible. There are quite a bit of resources available on this topic. Your question is very broad so I am pointing you to few resources that might help you get started https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources, https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on or take a look at this http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/

Comment: Check my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161429/combine-the-use-of-authentication-both-for-mvc-pages-and-for-web-api-pages/39797768#39797768

Comment: thanks for the links! however, I can't find any resource that explains how to implement actually a **sign-in** to MVC app using the JWT token. All resources just show how to authenticate on WebAPI side. Am I missing something?

Comment: My answer has the MVC piece as well (scroll down a bit in my answer). I am also putting a sample MVC app in GitHub will share the link once it is ready.