# What's the added value of using IdentityServer 4 with ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

**TL;DR** - Headline :)

**Background story:**
I'm building a set of applications (including RESTful APIs, and several clients - pure web apps, and mobile apps). 
All the core APIs are going to be written in `ASP.NET Core`. 
I want to tackle the authentication-authorization issue.

I don't want to use a cloud or an external service since keeping all the user related data close is in top priority for me (including passwords).

From what I read, it seems like that `ASP.NET Core Identity` provide all the functionality and processes related to authentication and authorization needed. I can manage a whole user base, including hashed passwords, and all the data-related to a user by myself. It's a collection of abstractions and concretes (which I can extend if needed).

I also read that I can integrate with `IdentityServer 4`. From what I understand, it grants me an extra layer of security, in a way that I can use it as a security token service (STS) and provides me with the implementation of OAuth 2.0 authorization and OpenID authentication which is great, BUT... is that it? I just want to understand what's my benefit of using it.

**My question has 2 parts :**

1. What's in between ASP.NET core Identity and IdentityServer 4? 
   Does IdentityServer 4 supply some (different) concretes of the abstractions that ASP.NET Identity's provide?
   I want to know the relation between ASP.NET Identity and IdentityServer 4.
2. What's the cost of developing with IdentityServer 4? Is it straight-forward, or it's not the trivial to implement?
3. A bonus question :) - Are there any alternatives out there? What would you choose? And why?

[the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121854/net-core-identity-server-4-authentication-vs-storing-users-table-and-returning) has an EXCELLENT answer, which answered a lot of my questions, but I still want an answer specific to my questions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, if it's not obvious by now: You can't create jwt/bearer tokens with ASP.NET Core Identity.

ASP.NET Core Identity uses cookie middleware, which has a few downsides. With the Authorization middlewares available you can consume bearer/jwt tokens, but you can't create your own ones. That's where ASOS & Identity4 close the gap.

Using cookies has several downsides, including the fact that it's generally long lived whereas JWT tokens usually have a short lifetime (5 to 10 minutes) and get refreshed via identity token.

So in case someone obtains a bearer token by eavesdropping the traffic, the token is only valid for a short period and the attacker can't refresh it without the id token.

Second, cookies are more vulnerable to [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), whereas bearer token are sent per request and are only vulnerable to XSRF, which can be more easily be protected via AntiForgery tokens. See also this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/148163/84658) on security stack exchange.

Comment: Just to make sure, when you said "With the Authorization middlewares available **you can** consume bearer/jwt tokens.", you meant "**you can't** consume bearer/jwt tokens" right?

Comment: No, you can consume it (i.e. one issued by Facebook or Google) with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` package. But you can't create and sign your own one.

Comment: @Tseng in which case the typo is in "but you **can** create your own ones", because i think you meant **can't** :)