# IdentityServer4 and Web API in same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4

I have an **IdentityServer** and a **MVC-Client**, IdentityServer has its own web API's to provide user management to its clients.
MVC client uses `HybridAndClientCredentials` grant type to interact with IdentityServer. I have no problem with authenticating client's user. The problem is when I try to call some API from IdentityServer with authenticated user, server returns login view instead of API's result.

Here is my client configuration:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc.identity.management",
    ClientName = "Identity Management",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,

    RequireConsent = false,

    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("somesecret".Sha256())
    },

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5001/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5001/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
    }
}
```

And client

```
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientSecret = "somesecret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

        options.ClientId = "mvc.identity.management";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });
```

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Why are you calling an API From your identity server?  You're user is authenticated, the user should call the API,  Or the IdentityServer, should have its own credentials to call the api.

Comment: I'm calling API within my Client

Comment: Where the code for your api, your api needs to validate that token against identity server

Comment: Exactly, that's the problem, I'm able to get access_token from server and set HttpClient bearer, but when I try to call API instead of result, server returns a login view as String to client.

Comment: post your start up code for the API, the Api needs to validate the token back against Identity Server.

Comment: Both API and IdentityServer are in the same project. Not separated. Client which is MVC application calls API inside IdentityServer. I know if API was in separate project should validate token by given authority against server. But I have both in same project.

Comment: the token server probably shouldn't be a part of  your api.  But given that you've decided to use this archiecture, my guess IdentityServer only validates the cookie for their methods, and you need to create an Authorization policy to verify the cookie for your methods still.  I would recommend starting from a clone of one of their test projects.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail or point some sample, I almost read and examined all their project, but no luck.

Comment: I'll describe the flow I know best.   I usually use JWT so I don't need XSRF Tokens, Login to the server the server returns a token,  Then token is appended to the head of the request made to the api.  The api has an authorization policy which grabs out the token from the header, and then the API makes a call back to IdentityServer to Validate the user is logged in.  For more information check out this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121854/net-core-identity-server-4-authentication-vs-identity-authentication).  TBH OIDC is quite confusing, starting from the examples is the ...

Comment: easiest way to full understand a flow because, you're start from a point where something is already working

Comment: I believe `id_token` should be used for these purposes, not `access_token`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late but this question may arise for others.
the solution is to use the `LocalApi` which is a built in feature of `IdentityServer4`.
You create a `LocalApi` and authorize it with a custom scope which your clients should add that scope which is `IdentityServerApi`.
The complete resource is available here:
https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html