# which authentiation to use

Tags: security, authentication, single-sign-on, token

Our application is currently written in .NET Framework + Razor, and traditional Membership authentication.

I am trying to modernize it, so I stawted to work on a .net core + react solution, but it has to cooperate with the existing application.

So currently, we have the old monolit, and an other .net core apis, called by react. The react is embedded inside the Razor.

Now I need to choose what authentication to use. I guess membership and other session based authentications can't be used, because there are multiple apps in multiple domains. So I need tokens.

I am not really sure about which solution can or should I use. I know buzzwords like bearer token, .NET Identity, OAuth + OpenId, but can I use any of them in this situation, to use it to protect the API and as well for the "traditional" razor app?
And where should I store the token? Should I store it in a session of the razor app, and pass it to the React too?

I need a solution where user credentials are stored in our own database, not something list Google's or Facebook's single sign on.

Is there a good tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for a lot here. I would suggest brushing up on this topic from the beginning. If you only know the buzz words you won't get anywhere quick. I can give some quick advice but if you aren't familiar with the basics this won't really help. There is no quick solution for your answer.

I would suggest ***authentication*** on the edge of the application to achieve a nice separation to work with the existing app. I would create a light weight method that receives the request from the client and gives the api gateway proof of the user identity in a way the API can verify.  I would go with ***OAuth and OpenId Connect*** protocol to achieve this separation. Also, take a look at [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/), it  is  an  open  source  product  that  makes  it  easy  to  implement  single  sign-on  and  access  control(Authentication)  in  web  applications  and  HTTP APIs.

- OpenId  Connect  to  authenticate  users
- OAuth  to  limit  collaboration for these light weight method calls
- JSON  Web  Tokens  (JWTs)  for  user identities

Now the problem with this solution is that there is a high level of trust between this light weight method call and the rest of the system. The principle of ***defense in depth*** would suggest to implement a layering strategy, so that if this layer is compromised another layer is there as the next line of defense. I'll leave the rest up to you.

Comment: oh I know that OpenId is for authenticatino and OAuth is auhhorization, I know they use tokens, but how is it different from .net Identity? And simple JwtSecurityToken like this:
https://jonhilton.net/2017/10/11/secure-your-asp.net-core-2.0-api-part-1---issuing-a-jwt/
Works? works. so why openid and oauth? And why .net identity? and why IdentityServer4?
But most importamntly, can I use all of them is my case?

Comment: It's a long answer, I would suggest looking at these answer that answer all of your questions. And You can use it with your app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121854/net-core-identity-server-4-authentication-vs-identity-authentication