# Skip identity server 4 login page and put IDP & resource server on the same domain

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

When using identity server4 authorization code flow, does it have to be redirected to a IDP domain to get authenticated?

For example,

- angular client side app runs at localhost:4200
- IDP identity server 4 runs at localhost:5000
- resource api server runs at localhost:3000

1. Can I just use my client side login page instead of being redirected to IDP and use their login page?
2. Is it possible to put IDP identity 4 & resource server in one place? so they can be run at the same port (ex: localhost:3000)

I don't think it's reasonable to deploy three times (client, IDP, resource) on a separate domain when my app is relatively small and auth will not be shared by other client apps.

What's the best approach for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to login on the client side by using the resource owner password credentials grant, which is something you should never ever do. [Read here why](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications).
Combining the IDP and the resource API on the same port is also something you should not even try to do. The IDP, Clients and Resources are all separate entities. If you wish to use Identity Server, and use it correctly, what you currently have is correct: a client using Identity Server for user auth, and a resource which the client is granted use of by the IS. If you wish to only have a client with a login page and a API, you can make that, in which case you don't need Identity Server.

Comment: Thanks. If I wish to have a client with a login page & api, what's the approach?

Comment: The api will be handling the authentification. If you are using net core, you can easily set up auth when creating a new project (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-web-api-with-json-web-tokens/Images/01%20Create%20Web%20API.png) here in upper right corner. If you wish to do it your self or aren't using net core, a simple google search will sufice.

Comment: thanks, but in that case it's going to be a password flow isn't it?

Comment: Um, well not exactly. Password flow is a flow made for old old legacy apps, and flows are a part of idp. Using an Idp is kinda different then having your own login logic. You should read up on it, here is a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42475868/11320426

Comment: a quote from that answer: "If you just need a users table with password sign in capabilities and a user profile, then ASP.NET Identity is perfect. No need to involve external authorities. But, if have many applications needing to access many apis, then an independent authority to secure and validate identity and access tokens makes sense. IdentityServer is a good fit, or see openiddict-core, or Auth0 for a cloud solution."

Answer (score 2):

I agree with LucaBNW that keeping IdentitySerer as a separate service is a good idea, becuase it get much harder to reason about what is happening when things break when they are in the same service.

If you have them on a separate domain or on the same domain but with separate ports does not matter (security-wise) because they are still considered different origins when the port are not the same.

if you do want to use OAuth/OpenID-Connect/IdentityServer, you should never ever use your own login screen. You should always redirect to the IDP. It's a big no-no, security wise. Because as a user you don't know where you actually login-to, and how well your UI handles the username/password.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to deploy client app and IDP on the same domain then? It seems weird to me to get redirected to IDP domain from client app domain

Comment: Same domain is OK, same port isn't. So if we consider example.com to be the domain, your idp would be on idp.example.com and your api on api.example.com. Same with localhost, in your case port 5000 and 3000.

Comment: i see. so `idp` from idp.example.com is the port number in domain?

Comment: yeah, idp is an app itself so should always hosted on its own address.

Comment: No, IDP is not the port number, the port number is the number after the domain, like idp.example.com:8080 or idp.example.com:5001   , so you can host multiple sites/services on the same domain but with different ports... By default the port is 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS